# Gradle Error: Path is not a readable directory for an Android Project saved in OneDrive

Tags: android-studio, gradle, flutter, onedrive

I tried to use a OneDrive folder to store my Flutter project [Windows 10, Android Studio]. I then made edits to it on another machine [same configurations]. The project compiled fine on the first machine initially and on the second one after the changes. Running it on the first machine again after the changes I get the below error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. 

Path "build/[package]/intermediaries/compiled_local_resources" is not a readable directory.
```

I've tried a number of solutions mentioned in similar, though not equivalent issues:

1. Updating Android Studio
2. Running Android Studio as Administrator
3. Removing the [package] from my dependencies (this resulted in a
   different package being identified in the error message).
4. Pressing File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...
5. Commenting out
   "org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M" in gradle.properties
6. Doing:

```sh
cd android 
gradlew clean
```

None of this worked.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

I had the same problem today:

```
Path "build/[package]/intermediaries/compiled_local_resources/debug/out" is not a readable directory.
```

I was able to fix this issue by deleting the .gradle and rebuilding the project.

Comment: every time I face this error I come here to solve it and try to upvote your answer, but it is already upvoted, thanks a lot.

Comment: .gradle is a folder in the android folder.

Comment: @Mr.ZeroOne its also hidden for those who cant see it

Comment: Fixed my issue. Thanks for this.

Comment: If you create an empty folder `./debug/out` that works too

Answer (score 5):

All I did was create the (empty) directory that it was looking for and it built fine afterward.

```
mkdir -p compiled_local_resources/debug/out
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, came out of no where and it really shouldn't make the build fail... but all I did was create the (empty) directory that it was looking for and it built fine afterwards.

Comment: Didn't work for me: the subfolders `compiled_local_resources\debug\out\` that I created got deleted on build.

Answer (score 2):

In the end the only thing that worked for me was pushing the project up to a Git remote and cloning it from there into another (local) directory.

[not sure this counts as a solution but nothing else worked for me after a long agonising search so hopefully it helps someone]

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! The .gradle solution didn't work for me so I recloned my project and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I know the OP had Windows, but if it helps anyone else in the future:

On Mac OS I discovered (the hard way) that Android Studio and Flutter do not play nice with being stored in iCloud! I noticed that some files weren't available locally and that's what was causing the problem for me. I moved my project out of iCloud (forcing it to download the missing files forever) and then it was fine.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the `android/.gradle` folder worked for me.

Comment: This solution works for me.

Answer (score 0):

+1 also to the #1 answer (Vadow).  As I do not have 50 points yet was not able to add this as a comment, so will have to post separately.

Like the OP, I have two machines - and got into trouble (Synology Drive).  Vadow's solution worked for me, but I also had to do:

- Flutter Clean
- Flutter Pub Get

on the terminal and from within the project directory to get things follow back up and running.

Thank you Stackoverflow, and thank you Vadow!