# FAILURE: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: android, flutter

I am getting this error while I am running app (flutter run)

```
event sent after app closed: {id: 0, progressId: null, message: Running "flutter pub get" in de_p_city_guide...}
event sent after app closed: {id: 0, progressId: null, finished: true}
Launching lib\main.dart on Nokia 5 3 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Plugin project :firebase_core_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Path 'D:\Lets_Go\de_p_city_guide\build\screen\intermediates\compiled_local_resources\debug\out' is not a readable directory.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 53s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Solution I tried but didn't work :

- flutter clean
- File > Invalidate Caches/Restart...
- Adding (org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m) to gradle.properties
- Adding to android/app/build.gradle:

  android {
  aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
  aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
  }
- I removed my cash data from .../User/.gradle/cashes
- I deleted the .gradle and rebuilding the project

**Any Help Please here**

Answer (score 0):

Error in

```sh
Plugin project :firebase_core_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
```

Solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61732409/plugin-project-firebase-core-web-not-found).

Comment: It was running before with this note, it doesn't effect it,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60483656/gradle-error-path-is-not-a-readable-directory-for-an-android-project-saved-in-o

Comment: I did it, I deleted the .gradle and rebuilding the project but it didn't work